# QUESTION.Display clientid and clientname of the client(s) having 21 anywhere in their contact number

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientid, clientname
FROM client
WHERE contactno LIKE '%21%'
```

Comment: what is the issue with your current query and which db you are using to run your queries? Share input data and expected output in the question.

Comment: Please do as @PrabhakarReddy said. Otherwise there can be no answers, just guesses, like about your column data types, `contactNo` not being a string for example? https://dbfiddle.uk/ldnYNSjE

Comment: Column contactno data type?